# generate datetime with loop for or foreach

Tags: php, datetime, date

is possible generate datatime with loop for or foreach with 30 minutes intervals?

for example:

```
for($i=0;$i<?;$i ??){
echo ;
}
```

now is **2011-12-18 02:24:00**

and i would like receive:

```
2011-12-18 02:00:00
2011-12-18 02:54:00
2011-12-18 03:24:00
2011-12-18 03:54:00
2011-12-18 04:24:00
2011-12-18 04:54:00
2011-12-18 05:24:00
```

Comment: Where does `2011-12-18 02:00:00` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) for this:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();

echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $datetime->modify('+30 minutes');

    echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/5RUmqwa3)

Comment: @middus: You know the performance gain of using comma is very small right? I think consistency in my code is more important than 0.000001 millisecond performance gain.

Comment: It's just a pet peeve of mine - why concat if there's no need to. I'm sorry if you did not like my edit. Shall I rollback?

Comment: @middus Neh let it be. I've added my comment. That should leave the choice to OP which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be implemented using php's `time()` function and adding 30*60 seconds.

```
$time = time();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
  // add 30 minutes à 60 seconds
  $time += 30*60;
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time), "\n";
}
```

[See a demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/y6ZGy6WV)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sStartDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
  echo '<br />'.$sStartDate  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+30 minutes', strtotime($sStartDate)));
}
```